# Filter Photos from photo library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to save some photos in photo library using UIImagePickerController and  save that name in my database. At the same way I need to view that saved photos. I don't want to see all photos in photo library . Which is the better way? please post some samples.

Answer (score 0):

You are going the wrong way for what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to have application specific pictures saved, and the user only be able to see those, you are going to have to use the method UIImageJpedRepresentation method that gives  you back an NSDAta object representation of the image, then you want to store the data using the file system or core data, along iwth its naming information etc. When you want to display images to the user, you should be able to retrieve the data and use [UIIMage  imageWithData:data] method to get your images back and display them. Hope this helps